# Fetch all rows from a big table in SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a table with over 500K records, and when I try to fetch a filtered result set (~145K records) my closeConnection() method crashes. After debugging, it turns out that the statement object gets 1000 records at a time, and the connection drops in the middle of the next fetch round.
As I work with framework (employer's framework) I cannot change the timeout setting, but I was thinking about fetching the whole bulk of records at once. FYI, Performance is not an issue here, so it does not matter if it takes longer.

Is there anything like ALL_ROWS hint in oracle that give me the same results in SQL server? or maybe some other solution?

This the query:

```
SELECT MODEL.MODEL_TABLE_CODE VARIANT_ID, MODEL.DSC, MODEL.MAIN_MODEL_ID, MODEL.YEAR_FROM, MODEL_DN.SHOW_IN_PORTAL, MODEL.DISCONTINUE_DATE
FROM T_MODEL MODEL, T_MODEL_DN MODEL_DN
WHERE MODEL.MODEL_TABLE_CODE = MODEL_DN.ID
AND MODEL_DN.CHANNEL_TYPE_ID = @channel_type_id
AND MODEL.MAIN_VEHICLE_TYPE_ID = @main_vehicle_type_id
AND MODEL.UPDATE_DATE > @from_date
```

This is what I get in the log:

> [18-05-18 06:49:03.661] ERROR default task-62 [] com.idit.framework.backend.interceptor.SessionBeanInterceptor - 
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1222) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1105) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:646) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.assemble(ManyToOneType.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.assemble(TypeHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl.assemble(StandardCacheEntryImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.convertCacheEntryToEntity(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:754) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.processCachedEntry(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:625) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1222) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2776) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2750) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1058) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final.jar!/:5.2.5.Final]
>   Blockquote

Thanks

Comment: you can try with `BEGIN TRANSACTION <YOUR SQL STATEMENT> COMMIT TRANSACTION`

Comment: @B3S That is the wrong thing to do when using JDBC, the Java API for querying database.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and relevant exception messages

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it sounds interesting.. im not a java expert and i'll be courious to know what exactly are the negative impacts by using this with jdbc provider. Thanks in advance if you have any link to share and sorry to the OP if my tip missled him.

Comment: @B3S The JDBC driver handles transactions (either using a form of auto-commit, or with explicit transaction boundaries using methods in its API). Trying to handle transactions outside of the API methods of controlling transactions is explicitly discouraged because it can bring the connection in an incorrect state that can subsequently lead to other errors.